# Joomla login page, if user is already logged redirect to home page

Tags: php, authentication, joomla, redirect

I think I'm missing something in the Joomla login behaviour. 
I read a lot of post but can't find the answer of what I looking for.
Let's say you have login page (ie: yoursite.com/login), if you login, Joomla correctly brings you to the target page you choose. 
The problem is : 
if you then go back to the login page yoursite.com/login, the redirect doesn't work no more. In fact if you refresh the page the login fields vanish and all it remains is the logout button.

I tried

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();

if($user->id == 1)
{
// redirect here
}
```

I tried in Joomla 2.5 and 3.x, the behaviour is the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: Where is this code located? It needs to run on every page load. Try `if( !$user->guest )`, this works for every user. Currently your are redirecting only one user, with ID of `1`.

Comment: Hi Rene, the code is in a custom override com_users/login. It's a closed website, you have to login to see contents. So I need that if a user is already logged in, if he reload the login page will automatically sent to home contents. I'll try your suggestion

Comment: Try the if I recommended.

Comment: Thanks Rene, if( !$user->guest ) works good :)

Comment: This is exactly the behavior I would expect. Why would you want to prevent someone from getting the logout button if they want it?

Comment: The logout button is still there, but in a different layout (in a top menu area). The issue was that if a user already logged in tries to load mysite.com/login should be automatically redirected to homepage. By default, Joomla load the logout view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's not the same layout.

If the user is guest, you are looking at the "default_login.php" layout, which - I gather - is the one you already modified.
But if the user is logged, you are looking at the "default_logout.php" layout, which you need to override as well.

Comment: Thanks Francesco, when you go back to the login page Joomla loads the "default_logout.php" 
I tried a redirect in that file and it worked :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I said (or at least what I meant :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Before you redirect to home page or any other page you must called getApplication like this.

```
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
$user = JFactory::getUser();
if($user->id == 1)
 {
    // redirect here
    $mainframe->redirect('index.php');
 }else{
     // redirect to login page
    $mainframe->redirect('login');
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Dilip, I'll try to implement you suggestion too :)